Will this design pull GPIO_9 down while pulling GPIO_8 high?
I'm trying to use a tactile switch to set 2 pins for a boot mode. (ESP32-C6, for program download, GPIO_9 should be low, GPIO_8 should be high). Will this design perform as I expect it to? (unfortunately, I don't have the components to test it on a bread board). I've come up with this to replicate the functionality of a DPDT switch (without dual COM).


Missing base resistors.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You could easily check this on a simulator and see if it works. See the circuit above. When you connect the base of Q1 to 3.3V, you can see that the voltage on GPIO_9 is particularly of a concern because it is at something like 1.984V and not 0V. Besides other problems, this is an issue.
Can the following work for you?

simulate this circuit
Also, what about debouncing? Will the ESP take care of it?

Re: Debouncing - good question. As it only does anything on power-up, I suspect debouncing isn't necessary, since only the levels are being checked.
However, playing around with the circuit you made, I swapped Q1 to a PNP Transistor, moved the switch between Q1's Base and ground, put GPIO_8 off the Emitter, and GPIO_9 off the Collector and it seems to resut in 3.3v for 8 and 0.0v for 9.

I just found a similar question to mine here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188040/dpdt-switch-using-only-transistors
It seems it's much more complicated than I initially thought.

I am not sure to understand. Is there any other requirement that you didn't specify?

No - my apologies. The comments helped me think a bit differently about the issue. I've decided to go with a paired NPN/PNP transistor.

Short: No, this won't work like you intended.
Longe: Look at the path from +3.3V trough Collector-Emiter of Q301, Base-Emitter of Q302 and trough R308.
Let's assume Q302 is saturated, so will habe a voltage drop of about 200mV to 400mV. This will pull pull GPIO_8 to around 3V which is good.
From there we have basically a diode in Basis-Emitter of Q302 which will drop around 0.7V.
So this leaves us with 3.3V - 0.3V - 0.7V = 2.3V at R1.
I'd suggest something like that:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I think the labels got transposed - running this gives 3.3 to GPIO_9 and 0.92v for GPIO_8, but I get the gist of it. I think I'll go with @sai answer due to fewer components in use. This has helped me understand it much better.

@JoshuaT not the labels are switched. But in my example, the switch was open (changed that now)...
